# Boost ASIO reads from serial port cause lost data on timeout

Tags: c++, windows, boost, serial-port

I'm using Boost ASIO (version 1.64.0) to perform asynchronous reads from a serial port on Windows using timeouts.

I'm doing this by configuring a timeout handler and a read handler, and setting them up like this:

```
port->async_read_some(buffer, readHandler);
timer.expires_from_now(timeoutMilisec);
timer.async_wait(timeoutHandler);
```

In the timeout handler, if there is no error I call `port->cancel()`

The problem I'm having is that if this timeout event occurs exactly at the time data is arriving to the serial port, that data is lost.  It is not picked up in the readHandler that was just cancelled (which returns with an error).  It is not picked up in a subsequent call to `async_read_some`.  Is there any way to perform an asynchornous serial port read in which there is not a risk of data loss?  Does `port->cancel()` not prevent data loss?

Note: I verified the problem is with timing by setting my timeout period to approximately 1/2 the message interval.  It doesn't always happen, but about 1 of 10 messages are lost.  If I change the timeout period to always be longer than the message interval, I don't see the issue (although I presume it **could** occur to the very 1st message if I were unlucky).

Edit:  I worked around the problem by never cancelling the `async_read_some()` operation.  Instead I collect the read data into a buffer my application controls (and I use that intermediate buffer to determine if requests timed out or not).  I'm still of the opinion that Boost ASIO is doing something wrong by potentially losing data on `port->cancel()`, but would love to hear an explanation if anyone knows the details.  Perhaps there's something about the Windows serial port API that makes this impossible.  In my prior experience with Linux I've been able to easily select() on a serial port without consuming data.

Comment: rather than cancel the read, could you keep a producer-consumer queue of events (i.e. data arrived or timeout)?

Comment: @RichardHodges I think that's what I'm going to end up having to do.  I'll essentially let the read events happen indefinitely and keep an internal buffer of data that comes in.